# D3js responsive stacked bar chart - other topics solutions not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am fairly new to D3 and javascript. Very useful library, though. But I am having trouble to make my stacked bar chart (I got the code from D3js.org website) responsive. Actually, I have problems making all kinds of D3 charts responsive when I start from scratch .

I tried using `viewbox` attribute and also `preserveAspectRatio`, but I am probably doing it wrong.

Here is my entire code: http://codepen.io/voltdatalab/pen/avMoMx

```
var svg = d3.select("graph").append("svg")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr('preserveAspectRatio','xMinYMid')
    .attr('viewBox','0 100% '+Math.min(width,height)+' '+Math.min(width,height))
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Could someone give me a hand with this?

Comment: Take a look at these resources: http://eyeseast.github.io/visible-data/2013/08/28/responsive-charts-with-d3/, http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/ and https://colingourlay.github.io/presentations/reusable-responsive-charts-with-d3js/#/52.

Comment: Codepen does not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the viewbox attribute first. Try this:

```
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + (width) + " " + (height))
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin");
```

For this to work, you have to change your html:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Also had to take out the axis `.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"`

Comment: Thanks, my friend, very helpful.